# raspberry pi remote desktop

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I have a model B raspberry pi connected over an ethernet cable to my laptop. My tv has a hdmi input but my laptop has no hdmi output. I can display the raspberry pi desktop on the tv using a hdmi cable.

I want to use a remote desktop connection on the raspberry pi to display the laptops desktop on the tv. What software will allow me to do this?

Note: I am interested in software only, buying connectors or cables is not an option.

Edit: My laptop is running Windows 7 and my raspberry pi is running raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

The X11 protocol by itself allows you to do that. You should enable the **XDMCPServer** option in your laptop computer and then some login managers (such as kdm) will let you do a login from the raspberry directly on the laptop, forwarding everything on the network.

Please note that kdm has a bug so on the laptop is better if you use lightdm as login manager on the laptop (I've wasted a few hours because of this bug).

In my lightdm.conf on the laptop i have this section:

```
[XDMCPServer]
enabled=true
#port=177
key=
```

On kdm on the raspberry (or whatever similar *DM you want to use), you should disable the fancy graphical mode, it will show more buttons, and one of them will let you do the network login, which will automatically show the laptop on a list, and let you login to it.

Answer (score 0):

After edit question isn't seem to be about linux. You could use VNC or rdesktop/freerdp.